# Cannot access certain websites

Tags: windows-8.1, internet, user-accounts

I'm using windows 8.1 and all of a sudden, I cannot access certain websites (like facebook, youtube) under my own user account. But I can access google or yahoo. It's the same either I use IE or Chrome, even after I reset the internet options. I tried to ping facebook.com, and it seems normal.

However, when I switch to the guest account, everything seems fine. Could there be anything specific to my account causing this problem?

Thanks.

EDIT: I just ran a full scan of my computer using bitdefender, but no luck.

EDIT2: Even after I restore my PC to factory settings and create a local account, the problem still persists.

Comment: So the problem persists after a complete factory reset? Is it always the same set of sites you cannot reach or does it vary? Also, can you test with a different modem/router?

Comment: @Karan what I did was going to PC setting -> Update and recovery -> Recovery -> Remove everything and reinstall windows, then click "get started". I believe it's the same set of sites that cannot be reached, no matter at home or in office.

Comment: If you did a complete Reset (instead of just a simple Refresh) then the OS shouldn't be at fault. However the fact that it happens at different locations is puzzling. What is the content of your hosts file? Also, do you have any third-party firewall (standalone or as part of an anti-malware product) that may be blocking these sites?

Comment: @Karan The hosts file contains nothing except comments, and I only have the default windows firewall.

Comment: No firewall in your AV suite? I assume these sites are unreachable only on this one system?

Comment: @Karan I'm using the default windows defender. And yes, it only happens to my laptop and my roommate's machine works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the `hosts` file.
Open your `hosts` (`C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) with editor or an other text editor and look for entries like *youtube.com* or *facebook.com*. If you finde something delete these lines (but first, backup your current hosts file), save it and try it again.
The problem should be fixed.

Comment: What error do you get when opening youtube.com or other non accessible sites?

Comment: I don't remember. I sent my computer for service 3 weeks ago and haven't got it back